# One record prior to MAX, second to highest

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am completely new to SQL so I apologize if this is a very obvious mistake. I am working on an Access database and I'm just trying to get the second-to-last donation associated with each member to help calculate when their membership will expire.

Despite adding the WHERE statement as suggested in answers to similar questions, the results are identical to my list of most recent donations for each member. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Results would just be:

| Member # | Second-to-last transaction |
| --- | --- |
| Member 1 | 2/23/2018 |

Right now it's still showing 3/4/2018 for member 1, but that's the most recent donation.

````
SELECT [MEMBER LIST].[MBR #], MAX(ABTRANSACTIONS.[TRNS DATE]) AS SECONDTOLASTRANSACTION

FROM [MEMBER LIST] INNER JOIN ABTRANSACTIONS ON ([MEMBER LIST].[FIRST NAME] = ABTRANSACTIONS.[FIRST NAME]) 
AND ([MEMBER LIST].[LAST NAME] = ABTRANSACTIONS.[LAST NAME])

WHERE [TRNS DATE] < ( SELECT MAX([TRNS DATE]) FROM ABTRANSACTIONS)

GROUP BY [MEMBER LIST].[MBR #]; ```
````

Comment: Please add sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want.

Comment: Bing: "access query second to last record". Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/query-to-get-the-next-to-last-record.150368/